# switching from a line chart to a bar chart using two functions - how to clear in between?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have some data that I want to represent as both a line chart and a bar chart (the bar chart will eventually have a year dropdown filter). 
The way I'm doing this is by having two buttons tied to separate functions, one that draws a line chart, one that draws a bar chart.

I'm not sure where in my code I need to exit/remove the previous chart. When the page loads, there is a line chart. When I click the "bar" button, it comes up, but the line chart is still there. I thought maybe I could add svg.exit().remove() at the very top of the function, but that prevents it from ever being drawn.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, along with any other thoughts on getting this to switch back and forth well.

Thanks!

[Plunker is here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/6GXVwkVmKdc4YyNJnFde?p=preview)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    body { font: 12px Arial;}

    path {
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    #legendContainer{
        position:absolute;
        top:60px;
        left:10px;
        overflow: auto;
        height:490px;
        width:110px;
    }
    #legend{
        width:90px;
        height:200px;
    }
    .legend {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-anchor: left;
    }
    .legendcheckbox{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #showAll{
        position:absolute;
        top:600px;
        left:880px;
    }
    #clearAll{
        position:absolute;
        top:600px;
        left:950px;
    }
    input{
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:5px 10px;
        background:#999;
        border:0;
        color:#fff;
    }
    #inds{
        position:absolute;
        top:35px;
        left:10px;
    }
    #linechart{
        position:absolute;
        top:5px;
        left:10px;
    }
    #barchart{
        position:absolute;
        top:5px;
        left:60px;  
    }
    .current, .default{
        background: #000000;
    }
    #bar{
        background:#ccc;
        color:#222;
        padding:8px 15px;
        margin-right:6px;
        border-radius:5px;
        float:left;
        width:20px; 
    }
    .active{
        background:#0b3774 !important;
        color:#fff !important;
    }
    .bar {
      fill: #0078a5;
    }

    .bar:hover {
      fill: #18b7f2;
    }

    #tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        padding: 4px 6px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border:1px solid #eee;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    #tooltip.hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <div id="charttypes">
            <input name="linechartButton"
             type="button"
             id="linechart"
             class="clickable default"
             value="Line"
             onclick="updateGraph(data)" />
            <input name="barchartButton"
             type="button"
         id="barchart"
             class="clickable"
             value="Bar"
             onclick="updateBarGraph(data)" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <select id="inds">
            <option value="apples" selected="selected">apples</option>
            <option value="pears">pears</option>
            <option value="tomatoes">tomatoes</option>
    </select>
    <div id="legendContainer" class="legendContainer">
        <svg id="legend"></svg>
    </div>
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
        <p><span id="state"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="showAll">
        <input name="showAllButton"
         type="button"
         value="Show All"
         onclick="showAll()" />
    </div>
    <div id="clearAll">
        <input name="clearAllButton"
         type="button"
         value="Clear All"
         onclick="clearAll()" />
    </div>
    <script>
    $(function() {
         $(".clickable").click(function() {
            $("#linechart").removeClass("default");
            $("#linechart").removeClass("current");
            $("#barchart").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
      });
    });

    function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
      var result = [];
      for (var produce in json) {
        if (json[produce][key] === value) {
          result.push(json[produce]);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }

    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 160},
        width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 550 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            padding = 0.25;

    // Parse the date / time
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    //for bar chart
    var xBar = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width - margin.left - margin.right], padding);


    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);

    // Define the line
    var stateline = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("cardinal")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

    // Adds the svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var data;

    // Get the data
    d3.json("data.json", function(error, json) {

      json.forEach(function(d) {
            d.value = +d.value;
      });

        d3.select('#inds')
                .on("change", function () {
                    var sect = document.getElementById("inds");
                    var section = sect.options[sect.selectedIndex].value;


                    data = filterJSON(json, 'produce', section);
                    if ($( "#linechart" ).is( ".current, .default")) {
                        return updateGraph(data);
                    } else if ($( "#barchart" ).hasClass( "current" )){
                      return updateBarGraph(data);
                    }

                });

                // generate initial graph
                data = filterJSON(json, 'produce', 'apples');
                updateGraph(data);

    });

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#48A36D",  "#0096ff", "#ff007e"]);

    function updateGraph(data) {

        data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.value = +d.value;
                d.year = parseDate(String(d.year));
                d.active = true;
            });

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
        y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

        // Nest the entries by state
        dataNest = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) {return d.state;})
            .entries(data);

            var result = dataNest.filter(function(val,idx, arr){
                      return $("." + val.key).attr("fill") != "#ccc" 
                      // matching the data with selector status
                    })

            var state = svg.selectAll("path")
          .data(result);

            state.enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "line");

            state.transition()
                .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return d.color = color(d.key); })
                .attr("id", function(d){ return 'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '');}) // assign ID
                .attr("d", function(d){
                    return stateline(d.values);
                });

            state.exit().remove();

            var legend = d3.select("#legend")
                .selectAll("text")
                .data(dataNest, function(d){return d.key});

                //checkboxes
                legend.enter().append("rect")
                  .attr("width", 10)
                  .attr("height", 10)
                  .attr("x", 0)
                  .attr("y", function (d, i) { return 0 +i*15; })  // spacing
                  .attr("fill",function(d) { 
                    return color(d.key);

                  })
                  .attr("class", function(d,i){return "legendcheckbox " + d.key})
                    .on("click", function(d){
                      d.active = !d.active;

                      d3.select(this).attr("fill", function(d){
                        if(d3.select(this).attr("fill")  == "#ccc"){
                          return color(d.key);
                        }else {
                          return "#ccc";
                        }
                      })


                     var result = dataNest.filter(function(val,idx, arr){
                 return $("." + val.key).attr("fill") != "#ccc" 
               // matching the data with selector status
              })

               // Hide or show the lines based on the ID
               svg.selectAll(".line").data(result, function(d){return d.key})
                 .enter()
                 .append("path")
                 .attr("class", "line")
                 .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return d.color = color(d.key); })
                .attr("d", function(d){
                        return stateline(d.values);
                 });

              svg.selectAll(".line").data(result, function(d){return d.key}).exit().remove()  

                    })

        // Add the Legend text
        legend.enter().append("text")
          .attr("x", 15)
          .attr("y", function(d,i){return 10 +i*15;})
          .attr("class", "legend");

            legend.transition()
          .style("fill", "#777" )
          .text(function(d){return d.key;});

            legend.exit().remove();

            svg.selectAll(".axis").remove();

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);
    };

    function clearAll(){
      d3.selectAll(".line")
        .transition().duration(100)
                .attr("d", function(d){
            return null;
          });
      d3.select("#legend").selectAll("rect")
      .transition().duration(100)
          .attr("fill", "#ccc");
    };

    function showAll(){
      d3.selectAll(".line")
        .transition().duration(100)
                .attr("d", function(d){
            return stateline(d.values);
          });
      d3.select("#legend").selectAll("rect")
      .attr("fill",function(d) {
        if (d.active == true){
           return color(d.key);
         }
       })
    };

    function updateBarGraph(data) {  

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.active = true;
        });

        data.sort(function(a,b) {return a.value-b.value;});

      xBar.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.state; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

        var color = d3.scale.category20b(); 

      var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data);

        bars
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
              .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                    //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
                    var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + xBar.rangeBand() + 100;
                    var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 + height / 2;
                    //Update the tooltip position and value
                    d3.select("#tooltip")
                        .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                        .style("top", yPosition + "px")                     
                        .select("#state")
                        .text(d.state + ": " + d.produce + ": " + d.year + ": " + d.value);
                    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
              })
              .on("mouseout", function() {
                    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
              })
                .on("click", function(d){
                    d3.select(this).style("fill", "#ff3300");
                });

        bars.transition()
                .attr("id", function(d){ return 'tag'+d.state.replace(/\s+/g, '');})
          .attr("x", function(d) { return xBar(d.state); })
          .attr("width", xBar.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.value); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

        bars.exit().remove();

        svg.selectAll(".axis").remove();

        var legend = d3.select("#legend")
                    .selectAll("text")
                    .data(data);

                    legend.enter().append("text")
                  .attr("x", 0)
                  .attr("y", function(d,i){return 10 +i*15;})
                  .attr("class", "legend")
                        .style("fill", "#0078a5")
                        .on("click", function(d){
                    // Determine if current line is visible 
                    d.active = !d.active;
                    // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
                    d3.select("#tag"+d.state.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
                            .transition()
                            .duration(100) 
                            .style("fill", "#ff3300");

                            var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + x.rangeBand() + 100;
                            var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 + height / 2;
                            //Update the tooltip position and value
                            d3.select("#tooltip")
                                .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                                .style("top", yPosition + "px")                     
                                .select("#state")
                                .text(d.state + ": " + d.year + ": " + d.value);
                            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
                        });

                  legend.transition()
                        .text(function(d){return d.state;}); 

                    legend.exit().remove();

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("value");
    };

    </script>
    </body>
```

Data:

```
[
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"131"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"231"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"191"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"302"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"31"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"331"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"291"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"250"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"11"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"230"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"185"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"310"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"171"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"121"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"231"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"202"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"73"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"151"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"399"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"140"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"146"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"130"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"195"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"pears",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"210"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"71"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"221"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"31"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"102"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"173"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"194"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"195"
    },
    {
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"230"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"216"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"184"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"125"
    },
    {
      "state":"Ohio",
      "produce":"tomatoes",
      "year":2015,
      "value":"150"
    }
    ]
```